# Postgres concurrent batch processing

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency

I have one Postgres table with `n` rows, and I want to process them chunk by chunk. Processing a chunk means that `k` items are selected, sent externally, and then deleted from the database. There is an independent service that writes rows to the table at random times.

This works fine when there is just one process, but with multiple concurrent processes they can try to access the same rows, and after one process deletes the batch, the other process would fail.

I looked into some approaches:

1. Use random `OFFSET` when selecting, to reduce the probability that two processes will select the same chunks of rows, but this still fails when the number of chunks in the table is low, as the probability of collision gets high.
2. Add a timestamp column `updated_at`. Then each process would set all the rows from the chunk to "now", and the select would only take rows with `updated_at` older than 5 minutes. This would prevent other processes to take the rows worked on by the current process. However, in the time interval where one process is selecting and setting the rows' `updated_at`, another process could still select them and introduce a collision (although the probability is a bit lower).
3. Use only one process to iterate over the chunks and dump them into a queue, then use parallel processing on the queue rather than the database. This solution still creates a single-process bottleneck on the process that reads the database and pushes the events to the queue.

This feels like a common use-case so I feel like there should be a reasonable way to achieve this better than these semi-solutions.

Comment: 0) write the entire table to a file, and cut this file up into chunks.

Comment: "This solution still creates a single-process bottleneck on the process that reads the database" This will only be a binding bottleneck if it is slower than the external process is.

Comment: What if the external process fails?

Comment: @jjanes The external process can actually be multiple processes that do upserts into the table, so it's quite likely that our one exporting process will be slower. If any of the writing processes fail, it doesn't really matter, they will just rerun, or in the worst  case, we will have no rows in the table (which is our desired result anyway, this table name is "in_flight", its only purpose is to have rows that should be sent externally and removed afterwards.